# Escape dollar sign in Argo CD ConfigMap

Tags: gitlab, yaml, argocd

When I deploy Argo CD, I want this key-value pair in argocd-cm ConfigMap: `oidc.config.clientSecret: $oidc.keycloak.clientSecret`

However, after I deploy Argo CD through the GitLab Pipeline, I get this instead: `oidc.config.clientSecret: .keycloak.clientSecret`.

`$oidc` disappears. My guess is that GitLab understands it as an env variable and since it doesn't exist it becomes an empty string. How can I make sure that `$oidc.keycloak.clientSecret` is deployed as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I know when using the 'envsubst' tool I can use an empty variable to overcome this. you could try: `$${DOLLAR}oidc.keycloak.clientSecret` (as long as the DOLLAR variable is not set)