How to escape '$' in ArgoCD parameters?
I have a helm chart and ArgoCD for deployment where I override values. However one of my values contains $ in its name. How to escape it then?
I've tried $$ and it just disappears the dollar sign.
Example:
Desired value in Kubernetes yaml: name$server
Value in ArgoCD parameter:
name$$server

Value in yaml:
nameserver

And not escaping it at all just means that ArgoCD takes it as a variable.
Example:
Value in ArgoCD parameter (undefined var server):
name$server

Value in yaml:
name


What do you mean by "ArgoCd parameter"?

Basically helm values, but overriden in ArgoCD

Have you also tried name$${DOLLAR}server? Similarly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306631/escape-dollar-sign-in-argo-cd-configmap. Also, related: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/7961

Yes, I've tried this and it didn't solve my problem. I just see an empty space.
