Pymongo query with dates returns no results
I have the following python 3.12.4 code that inserts a JSON in a mongoDB deployed locally through a docker container using dockerhub' image "mongo:4.4.7"
    myClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://%s:%s@%s" % (MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASS,                      MONGO_CONN), timeoutMS=10000)
    myDB = myClient[CLIENT_NAME]
    myCollection = myDB[COLLECTION_NAME]

    the_json = '{"id": "json1","thedate": "2020-05-11T12:22:34.876Z"}'
    myRecord = json.loads(the_json)
    # replace str date with python' datetime object
    myRecord["thedate"] = datetime.strptime(myRecord["thedate"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    insertionResult = myCollection.insert_one(myRecord)

    startDate = datetime(2020, 8, 12, 4, 21, 3, 923453)
    mySearch = myCollection.find({"thedate": {"$gt": startDate}})

The above code returns records correctly.
The problem starts when using the very same python code against the very same dockerhub' image and the same python libraries in a kubernetes cluster. In such case, no records are returned. The curious part is that, in such cluster deployment, when I execute a "mySearch = myCollection.find()" it gets all the records in the DB, so there are no connectivity issues...
I have tried several types of date types to perform the search such as:
startDate = datetime(2012, 11, 2, 11, 10, 13, 123123, pytz.UTC)
startDate = datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)- timedelta(days=7)
startDate = datetime(2013, 3, 12, 6, 54, 4, 123123)
startDate = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=4)

Just in case, the date of all containers:
MY PC DATE:      lun 21 oct 2024 18:27:08 CEST+0200
DATE MONGODB RUN IN DOCKERS LOCALLY: Mon Oct 21 16:26:43 UTC 2024 +0000
DATE MONGODB RUN IN KUBERNETES: Mon Oct 21 16:29:24 UTC 2024 +0000
DATE PYTHON CODE KUBERNETES: Mon Oct 21 16:30:44 UTC 2024 +0000

As you can see, the date is stored with ISOdate, which seems correct to me. When I perform the following check using Mongo CLI the data type of the date stored in the DB seems also fine:
> date_obj = db["collection-name"].findOne({ thestr: 'exampleFile' }).thedate 
ISODate("2024-10-15T11:59:59.111Z") 
> date_obj.toString() 
Tue Oct 15 2024 11:59:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)

Any clue about what could be happening? why is it working locally but not in kubernetes?
Thanks in advance!!

Hello! Some questions:

Can you add a "regular" record and read it (in Kubernetes)?
What does your manifest look like? (How did you deploy your application?)
Is it a minikube Kubernetes cluster? or kind? or k3d? or in a cloud platform?


Meanwhile, while you provide more information, let me post a snippet showing how I was able to have the Python client insert and read records from the MongoDB database, which is both deployed in the Kubernetes cluster.
Notice that the mongo URL is mongo-service.pythonclient.svc.cluster.local:27017". mongo-service is the name of the Service resource in Kubernetes used to connect to the mongo db instances at a stable endpoint.
You can kubectl apply -f <THE FILE BELOW>:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-service
  namespace: pythonclient
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
  namespace: pythonclient
spec:
  serviceName: mongo-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo:4.4.7
        env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: root
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: foo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pythonclient
  namespace: pythonclient
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: pythonclient
        image: python:latest
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - |-
            cd /usr/app/src
            pip install -r requirements.txt
            python3 pythonclient.py
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8001
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/app/src
          name: config
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: pythonclient-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pythonclient-config
  namespace: pythonclient
data:
  pythonclient.py: |
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    ##here goes the python code that save/reads from the mongoDB##
    import pymongo
    import json
    from datetime import datetime

    # docker run --rm -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=foo mongo:4.4.7
    MONGO_USERNAME = "root"
    MONGO_PASSWORD = "foo"

    MONGO_URL = "mongo-service.pythonclient.svc.cluster.local:27017"
    MONGO_CLIENT_NAME = "my-client"
    MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME = "my-collection"

    myClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://%s:%s@%s" % (MONGO_USERNAME, MONGO_PASSWORD, MONGO_URL), timeoutMS=1000)
    myClient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://%s:%s@%s" % (MONGO_USERNAME, MONGO_PASSWORD, MONGO_URL), timeoutMS=1000)
    myDB = myClient[MONGO_CLIENT_NAME]
    myCollection = myDB[MONGO_COLLECTION_NAME]

    the_json = '{"id": "json1","thestr": "exampleStr","theint": 11,"thedate": "2024-10-15T11:59:59.953Z"}'
    myRecord = json.loads(the_json)

    myRecord["thedate"] = datetime.strptime(myRecord["thedate"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
    insertionResult = myCollection.insert_one(myRecord)

    startDate = datetime(2024, 9, 24, 7, 51, 5, 953123)
    documents = myCollection.find({"thedate": {"$gt": startDate}})

    print()

    print('===> showing documents:')
    for doc in documents:
        print(doc)

    print('done')

  requirements.txt: |
    argon2-cffi==23.1.0
    argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
    blinker==1.8.2
    certifi==2024.8.30
    cffi==1.17.1
    click==8.1.7
    dnspython==2.6.1
    Flask==3.0.3
    flask-swagger-ui==4.11.1
    itsdangerous==2.2.0
    Jinja2==3.1.4
    joblib==1.4.2
    MarkupSafe==2.1.5
    minio==7.2.9
    paho-mqtt==2.1.0
    pycparser==2.22
    pycryptodome==3.21.0
    pymongo==4.10.1
    python-crontab==3.2.0
    python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
    pytz==2024.2
    six==1.16.0
    typing_extensions==4.12.2
    urllib3==2.2.3
    Werkzeug==3.0.3

You should see the following from kubectl logs -n pythonclient <THE JOB POD NAME>.
===> showing documents:
{'_id': ObjectId('6717bf86e93e55221ffc8ae9'), 'id': 'json1', 'thestr': 'exampleStr', 'theint': 11, 'thedate': datetime.datetime(2024, 10, 15, 11, 59, 59, 953000)}
done


I had great hopes with your example because the DB is deployed using a statefulset instead of a deployment, but unfortunatelly the result is the same... It seems that the condition for the comparison is never met, which don't make any sense because both container are UTC+0...

I have also tried changing the date format of the dates of your code to myRecord["thedate"] = datetime.strptime(myRecord["thedate"], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").astimezone(tz=pytz.utc) and startDate = datetime(2024, 5, 24, 7, 51, 5, 953123, pytz.UTC) but the result is the same...

Perhaps there is a delay, after insertionResult = myCollection.insert_one(myRecord) could you add a time.sleep(10) before retrieving the data by date?

Can you also share the output of print(startDate) ?
Also try startDate = "2024-09-24 07:51:05.953123", startDate = "2024-09-24T07:51:05.953123", startDate = "2024-03-15T11:59:59.953Z"

Hi Ryan! The "delay" assumption was one of my first guesses. I already tried it and it didn't work. Regarding the value of the startdate variable, for the code startDate = datetime(1990, 11, 17, 10, 0, 23, 953123, pytz.UTC) it returns 1990-11-17 10:00:23.953123+00:00. Regarding giving the startdate variable a STRING value, it doesn't work, because as stated in my previos comment, the value stored in the mongodb is ISODATE (check the mongo CLI lines of my previous comment)

By the way, the datatype of the previous search date is <class 'datetime.datetime'>, which as far as I know is the required data type for mongoDB. As stated in the main description, I have tried with several "startdate" and, as far as they are "datetime.datetime" all of them work in my local machine...

So far connection works, no delay issue, no timezone issue, other simple queries work, and the record is in indeed in the database. For some reason either gt is broken (which I don't think is), or there is some other mysterious thing happening.
Is this Kubernetes cluster locally running on your machine via something like minikube? Or is it a remote cluster? Can you try the example provided in the answer in a minikube/kind environment locally on your machine?

Can you check the gt for the theint field (at least we can rule the possibility that gt is broken in general)? I am pretty sure gt is not broken for a simple int. But it is possible that gt does not work very well with the dates.
This is a really interesting problem we have. I am looking forward to finding a solution to this. Let's try our best!

Ryan, your summary is quite good! Regarding executing it on miniKube, I am not familiarized with such tool and I am quite restricted to install new tools. Regarding your suggestion of executing a search by the INT, I have found something VERY interesting. The behaviour of such searchs are the same as with dates, when I execute mySearch = myCollection.find({'theint':{'$gt': 9}}) in my local machine it works, but when I execute it on the cluster it doesn't works... WTF is happening with the "gt"??

Can you try "$eq" or "$ne", actually the other ones in the mongo db manual ? Also it could be the dollar sign "$" that is not being interpreted correctly.
Now we are up to something. Try storing 'theint':{'$gt': 9}} in a variable and try printing it. Make sure it is printed in the container logs (kubectl logs <pod name> -n <namespace> -f). We want to see if the "$" is read as a "$".

Ok, the mySearch = myCollection.find({'theint':{'$eq': 11}}) in my local machine works as expected, but the same search does not work on the cluster. Regarding your second request, I have created the next varaible testvar = {'theint':{'$gt': 11}} (which is a <class 'dict'>) and the print result is {'theint': {'': 11}}. You were absolutelly right, the "$" sign does not appear!! what is happening??

So it appears the configmap contents are not read correctly. Can you check kubectl exec <pythonclient pod name> -n pythonclient -- cat /usr/app/src/pythonclient.py?

Also, because it is a job, make sure to include a long enough time.sleep(100) to give you enough time to execute the command to check the contents.

Also, try pythonclient.py: |- instead of pythonclient.py: |. It is a literal strip.

Or even a double dollar sign $$. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71306631/escape-dollar-sign-in-argo-cd-configmap

That's it! Basically, there are code chunks in the python code loaded from the configmap like thedate": {"$lt": endDate. Such code, when the YAML files are deployed using something like cat *.yaml | envsubst | kubectl apply -f - are replaced by " " (empty), causing this error... Thanks a lot Ryan!!!

Glad to help! But can you check one more thing: what does the contents of the configmap look like? Does it have the $? We need to know where this replacement is happening. At kubectl apply or mount time?

The replacement is happening before executing the KubeCtl, that is the reason why the ".py" file is loaded into the cluster without the "$lt"

Thanks! It would be a bit more of a serious problem if this happened at mount time instead of at the cmd line. But it is not the case.
